# Scala parser combinators and newline-delimited text

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am writing a Scala parser combinator grammar that reads newline-delimited word lists, where lists are separated by one or more blank lines. Given the following string:

```
cat
mouse
horse

apple
orange
pear
```

I would like to have it return `List(List(cat, mouse, horse), List(apple, orange, pear))`.

I wrote this basic grammar which treats word lists as newline-delimited words. Note that I had to override the default definition of `whitespace`.

```
import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object WordList extends RegexParsers {

    private val eol = sys.props("line.separator")

    override val whiteSpace = """[ \t]+""".r

    val list: Parser[List[String]] = repsep( """\w+""".r, eol)

    val lists: Parser[List[List[String]]] = repsep(list, eol)

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val s =
          """cat
            |mouse
            |horse
            |
            |apple
            |orange
            |pear""".stripMargin

        println(parseAll(lists, s))
    }
}
```

This incorrectly treats blank lines as empty word lists, i.e. it returns

```
[8.1] parsed: List(List(cat, mouse, horse), List(), List(apple, orange, pear))
```

(Note the empty list in the middle.)

I can put an optional end of line at the end of each list.

```
val list: Parser[List[String]] = repsep( """\w+""".r, eol) <~ opt(eol)
```

This handles the case where there is a single blank line between lists, but has the same problem with multiple blank lines.

I tried changing the `lists` definition to allow multiple end-of-line delimiters:

```
val lists:Parser[List[List[String]]] = repsep(list, rep(eol))
```

but this hangs on the above input.

What is the correct grammar that will handle multiple blank lines as delimiters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try setting [`skipWhitespace`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/RegexParsers.html#skipWhitespace:Boolean) to `false` instead of redefining the definition of whitespace. The issue you're having with the empty list is caused by the fact that `repsep` doesn't consume the line break at the end of the list. Instead, you should parse the line break (or possibly end of input) after each item:

```
import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object WordList extends RegexParsers {

  private val eoi = """\z""".r // end of input
  private val eol = sys.props("line.separator")
  private val separator = eoi | eol
  private val word = """\w+""".r

  override val skipWhitespace = false

  val list: Parser[List[String]] = rep(word <~ separator)

  val lists: Parser[List[List[String]]] = repsep(list, rep1(eol))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s =
      """cat
        |mouse
        |horse
        |
        |apple
        |orange
        |pear""".stripMargin

    println(parseAll(lists, s))
  }

}
```

Then again, parser combinators are a bit overkill here. You could get practically the same thing (but with Arrays instead of Lists) with something much simpler:

```
s.split("\n{2,}").map(_.split("\n"))
```

Comment: That works if there is only one blank line between word lists. If there are _n_ blank lines we end up with _n-1_ bogus empty lists in the middle. (BTW: the `skipWhitespace` and `eoi` examples are very helpful.)

Comment: @W.P.McNeill - I updated the code to look for `rep1(eol)` between lists of strings. Is that what you were going for?

Comment: `rep1(eol)` is what I was looking for. Thanks. I know that parser combinators are overkill here. I deliberately simplified the problem for the purposes of exposition.

Comment: In that case, +1 for deliberately simplifying the problem for purposes of exposition!