# Detecting new lines in RegexParsers

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am building this parser for a DSL where white space, including newlines, is generally ignored. The DSL contains various LISP style expressions, each of which has its own parser. Variables are declared as follows:

```
?varname
?varname1 ?varname2 - type1
?varname3 ?varname4 ?varname5 - type2
```

If there is no `-` after a variable, it defaults to the type `object`, while if there is a `-`, then the type name follows. So in the above case, `?varname` is of type `object` while `?varname1` and `?varname2` are of type `type1`.

I have used `RegexParsers` for my parser works perfectly for the rest of all the DSL. However, I have discovered a problem with parsing the above variable declaration list.

My parser for the above looks as follows:

```
def typed_list_variables : Parser[List[LiftedTerm]]= typed_variables.+ ^^ { case list => list.flatten.map(variable =>
        LiftedTerm(variable._1, variable._2 match {
          case "object" => ObjectType
          case _ => TermType(variable._2)
        })) }

def typed_variables = ((variable+) ~ (("-" ~> primitive_type)?)) ^^ {
    case variables ~ primitive_type => 
         for (variable <- variables) yield variable -> primitive_type.getOrElse("object")
}

def variable = """\?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r
def primitive_type = """[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r
```

The problem is that since I want to ignore whitespace, and I am using `RegexParsers` to do this, with its out of the box facility to skip whitespace, `?varname` gets mistakenly interpreted to also be of type `type`

Is there a way to detect this? I don't wish to modify all the rest of the parser to remove the skip white space, because its quite complex and will make it unreadable. What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine whitespace; exclude newline from it.

```
override val whiteSpace = """[ \t]+""".r
```

I'm not sure if this is considered good practice. Please have a look at this thread for further discussion and inspiration:
[Scala parser combinators and newline-delimited text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355238/scala-parser-combinators-and-newline-delimited-text)

*EDIT: further refinement based on input from OP; see also the comments made earlier.*

In this particular DSL, some statements (the declarations) are terminated by newline, while other statements consider newline as whitespace, merely separating tokens and to be ignored by the parser.

This inconsistent interpretation of newline may be too complicated for a simple regex. So in this case, instead of overriding the variable `val whiteSpace`, override the method `def handleWhiteSpace`; here you can programmatically determine what is to be considered as whitespace. The easiest approach seems to be to define a global modifiable variable (`var foo: Boolean`) that is toggled on and off by the tokenizer/parser, based on the type of statement that is being parsed. Your implementation of `handleWhiteSpace` can then use this variable to adjust its behaviour accordingly.

The new implementation of `handleWhiteSpace` can be a copy of the original `handleWhiteSpace`, where the unmodifiable `whiteSpace` is replaced by an expression that dynamically switches between two regular expressions (one matching all whitespace including newline, the other excluding newline), depending on the value of your global variable. If possible, you may want to make better use of inheritance and call `super.handleWhiteSpace` in either one of these cases.

Comment: But then wouldn't it also get excluded in the other places where I need to ignore it, and thus I have to cater for all of them in the rest of the parser or something like that? I can't put `\n*` in between all the tokens.

Comment: @jbx: In variable declarations, newline is a separator. For that matter, newline (`\n+`) should be defined as a token in the syntax of the DSL. Excluding newline from whitespace *would* become a problem if the DSL allows other statements to span multiple lines (a nasty syntactic inconsistency, but not insurmountable). But I am guessing here; please do tell more about the rest of the parser, and the role of newlines there.

Comment: Yes it is inconsistent in this regard unfortunately. It originally didn't support these type declarations with the dash (everything was the same), and they were added afterwards and they are optional for backwards compatibility. This is the only place I know where newlines make a difference, and comments (which start with a `;` and go on till the end of the line, but I had solved that by enhancing the whitespace regex to  `"""(\s|;.*)+"""`. These type declarations only happen once at the top of the file, so if I could turn off whitespace skipping at that point it would be ideal.

Comment: @jbx: The whitespace regex should be able use a look-behind assertion to ensure that newline is excluded for lines that start with `?` only. I was thinking about `override val whiteSpace = """(?m)((?<!^[ \t]*\?.*)\s+|[ \t]+)""".r`, but that may still have a bug.

Comment: This approach is interesting. Actually I have a similar case where there is no questionmark (it is when a type extends another type), so a bit screwed to use the questionmark as the indicator. However, I wonder if I could do something similar with the section where these types are declared, because they start with a special keyword `types`, but it could be several lines before that, including empty lines.

Comment: When it becomes too complicated for a regex, try overriding `protected def handleWhiteSpace`. I have no experience with that, but I saw this suggestion elsewhere on SO.

Comment: Actually creating a `var` stateful variable and toggling it on and off, depending on whether I want to skip whitespace or not seems to work. I then override `def handleWhiteSpace` to check for this variable and if it is on I call `super.handleWhiteSpace` otherwise I just return `offset`. Still refining it, but seems to work. Could you update this answer accordingly so that I select it as the closest answer and you get the bounty?

Comment: @jbx: I hope it works out well for you! I updated my answer; maybe you would like to edit it too, fix possible misunderstandings I made, and add a code sample of yours?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach for you to consider.

Write a simple preprocessor that appends an explicit separator token (something you make up yourself) to every line that starts with a question mark. Now your parser can ignore *all* newlines; declarations are explicitly terminated by an explicit token.

Comment: The question mark is not always there unfortunately. Forgot to include the types themselves which do not have the questionmark, but are declared exactly in the same way.

Comment: The preprocessor *can* be a separate parser; that way it should be possible to handle more complex rules as to what exactly is a declaration. But the goal is the same: append a terminator token to each declaration. It may seem silly, having a sequence of two parsers, but in this case, two separate parsers would be less complex than a single big one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the format you are trying to parse uses newline as a 
keyword you will have to consider the newline while parsing.

 On the bright side this is easely done and not so different from your original code.
Try creating a parser that is aware of the lines by adding a typed_variables_line function. Then define the document as a list of these lines. Also you want to allow for empty lines. I have added a rule for this as well.

```
override val whiteSpace = """[ \t]+""".r;
def typed_list_variables : Parser[List[LiftedTerm]]= rep(typed_variables_line | empty_line) ^^ { 
    case list => list.flatten
}

def typed_variables_line:Parser[List[LiftedTerm]] = rep1(variable) ~ opt("-"~>primitive_type) <~ opt("\n") ^^ {
    case vars ~ None =>vars.map(varName=>LiftedTerm(varName,ObjectType));
    case vars ~ Some(primTypeName) =>vars.map(varName=>LiftedTerm(varName,TermType(primTypeName)));
}

def empty_line:Parser[List[LiftedTerm]] = "\n" ^^ {
    case nothing => List();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately most of the other expressions can span multiple lines. So I will have to introduce the optional newline character in between all the possible tokens for this approach.

Comment: I have an idea that might solve this. It might be possible to craft an implicit which would wrap an expression with newline expressions. Maybe you could have some special parser type that would trigger the implicit? If you like I could try to construct this.

Answer (score -2):

I would strongly suggest keeping the syntax of your language so that newlines are not significant.

In my experience, making whitespace significant either leads to confusion on the part of users who don't know that it is, or to much more complex specification and processing of the syntax.

I think it's rarely worth the trouble. In particular, with the Scala RegexParsers it is non-trivial to ignore whitespace mostly but make it significant in some places (and be sure that you did it correctly).

Two suggestions for syntax variation:

a) add semicolons or some other terminator on the end of declarations, or

b) add commas or some other separator between the multiple varnames in a single declaration.

The modifications to your parser would be trivial and then you can move onto more interesting issues :-)

Comment: I can't vary the syntax. Its a standard DSL defined and used by others. I am just writing a parser for an existing language.  If I could change it I wouldn't even have asked the question.